# "Java live reload unavailable" after upgrade to 14.6.0

Tags: vaadin

I'm getting the "Java live reload unavailable"-box after upgrading from 14.4.7 to 14.6.0 with TravaOpenJDK 11.0.9.

[Screenshot of "Java live reload unavailable"-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gWhK.png)

Is there anything I might have missed in the release notes?

Comment: I checked the changes since Flow 2.4.5 (used in Vaadin 14.4.7) compared to Flow 2.6.0 and there is nothing directly changed regarding the live reload. So it either is a side effect of something or you've disabled the live reload somehow. Since TravaOpenJDK version 11.0.9 the live reload has been disabled by default, and you have to explicitly enable it. Have you done this ? https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/releases/tag/dcevm-11.0.9%2B1

Comment: I'm using Gradle with Spring Boot in IntelliJ, and I had included `-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar` in my IntelliJ's run configuration. But I didn't respect that `bootRun` is forking a new JVM! Don't know the coherence to the Vaadin upgrade, but at least it's working now for me after adding `-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar` to the `bootRun` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Gradle with Spring Boot in IntelliJ, and I had included `-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar` in my IntelliJ's run configuration. But I didn't respect that `bootRun` is forking a new JVM! Don't know the coherence to the Vaadin upgrade, but at least it's working now for me after adding `-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar` to the `bootRun` configuration.

In order to not force other developers to use TravaOpenJDK, I'm using this in my `build.gradle`:

```
def isUsingTravaOpenJDK() {
    // Vendor is AdoptOpenJDK, therefore we identify Trava by its version number:
    def knownTravaVersions = ["11.0.9+2-202011221400"]
    def currentJVM = System.getProperty("java.vm.version")
    return knownTravaVersions.contains(currentJVM)
}

bootRun {
    if (isUsingTravaOpenJDK()) {
        jvmArgs("-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar")
    }
}
```

It's currently not possible to use `java[.vm].vendor` to determine if Trava is used:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
    [...]
    java.vendor = AdoptOpenJDK
    java.vendor.url = https://adoptopenjdk.net/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues
    java.vendor.version = AdoptOpenJDK
    java.version = 11.0.9
    java.version.date = 2020-10-20
    [...]
    java.vm.vendor = AdoptOpenJDK
    java.vm.version = 11.0.9+2-202011221400
```

Comment: Does Trava not properly set `java.vendor` or `java.vm.vendor`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I'm unable to add a code block to this comment, I've updated my answer above to give some more background information why I need to use `java.vm.version` instead.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted when you have a moment.